# Block :before content is above my list and not on the left

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-lists

I tried to position a caracter "!" before a list. But the "!" is placing above the list and not and not on the left. What did I did wrong ? Here is my CSS

```
.cadreImportant{
padding:5px; 
background-color:#ffaca3; 
border:2px double #ff3924; 
border-radius:9px; 
text-align: left;
width:65%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.cadreImportant:before{
content: "!";
padding: 10px; 
font-size: 3em;
float: left;
text-align: center; 
margin-right: auto; 
margin-left: auto; 
height: 20px;
}
```

and here is my HTML Code :

```
  <div class="cadreImportant">
        <ul>
            <li>Sélectionner un manuel utilisateur dans la liste ci-dessus</li>
            <li>Après affichage du manuel,</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Cliquer dans le sommaire pour accéder au paragraphe correspondant</li>
                <li>Cliquer sur la flèche jaune pour remonter au sommaire</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Seems ok here: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/pazxd991/

Comment: which browser? working fine in chrome, firefox and IE10.

Comment: Yes it works all fine. Opera, Chrome , Firefox, and IE tested.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems working in all latest version. However as per **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)** stated that `width` should be specified while using `float`.

However you can use `position:relative` and `position:absolute`. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vurupadebase/1/edit)**.

**CSS Code..**

```
.cadreImportant{
padding:5px; 
background-color:#ffaca3; 
border:2px double #ff3924; 
border-radius:9px; 
text-align: left;
width:65%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 1em;
  position:relative;
}

.cadreImportant:before{
content: "!";
position:absolute;
display:block;
left:0;
padding: 10px; 
font-size: 3em;
/*float: left;
text-align: center; 
margin-right: auto; 
margin-left: auto; */
height: 20px;
}
```